# opening problem via ssh

Tags: gnome, ssh

I am using an ssh to connect to a remote server in Ubuntu. I want to open files pdf, html, txt etc.
I want to open it with a text editor, but for request for example gnome-open INSTALL_linux.txt it says:

```
(gnome-open:16187): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
GConf Error: No D-BUS daemon running

Error showing url: Error when getting information for file '/home/gamma/Documents/Gamma-Software/GAMMA_SOFTWARE-20150702/IPTA/INSTALL_linux.txt': No such file or directory
```

What should I do?

Comment: I doubt you can open a file with gnome-open via ssh only. Have you tried `ssh` with the `-Y`? This will forward your X11 session to your client. If you want to open a text file why don't you use an text-based editor like `vim`, `nano` or `emacs`? BTW: Don't open a pdf in an text-editor, that is a binary format and you will not be able to edit anything without breaking it.

Comment: yes nano is working,  but if I  want to open .html with chrome for example?

Comment: See my last comment: Use `ssh -Y YOUR_HOST` to enable X11 forwarding. Then you can open your html file in a browser. I don't know how, because I only use firefox but I would say `chrome /path/to/your/html.html` or something similar. BTW: man-pages are your friend!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible solution:

- [Copy the files to view to your local system](/q/157381/175814) and open them from there.
- [Open an SFTP connection](/q/349873/175814) to the server with a GVFS- or KIO-capable file manager (e. g. Nautilus, Nemo, Thunar, Dolphin, Konqueror) and open the files through it.
- [Use `sshfs` to mount a network file system over SSH](/q/412477/175814) and open the files through its mount point.
- In a similar fashion you can set up and use other remote file system services like NFS or CIFS/SMB/Samba.